# Spring: What happens when request matches multiple RequestMapping values?

Tags: spring, request-mapping, path-variables

If I have two controllers:

```
@RestController
public class ContentController {

    @GetMapping("/specialContent")
    public Map<String, String> handleSpecialContent() {
        Map<String, String> map = handleContent("specialContent");
        map.put("special", "true");
        return map;
    }

    @GetMapping("/{content}")
    public Map<String, String> handleContent(@PathVariable String content) {
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("content", content);
        return map;
    }

}
```

Is it guaranteed to go to `handleSpecialContent()` if I type '/specialContent' in the URL?
I could not find this on the internet

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring will match the handler to your explicitly defined mapping, so if you send a `GET` request to `/specialContent`, it's going to invoke your method marked as `@GetMapping("/specialContent")`.

If you'd like to learn how Spring matches, set a breakpoint in `org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet#getHandler(HttpServletRequest request)` and send your request.